# Unzipping a single file from Archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, unzip

I'm trying to port an existing Android application to iOS,
In the Android application i was using a ZipInputStream to extract a single file from the zip archive and store it in as a temporary file.

How could i extract a single file from a Zip Archive without having to extract the whole archive (As it is very large)?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I just edited the question to make it more generic. I would be happy even with plain Foundation

Comment: Generic questions aren't made for Stack Overflow either. They'll be a subject to deletion for being *too broad*, because: *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*.

For such generic questions you should refer to forums or chat rooms.

Comment: @Neeku: I disagree with your view. The task the OP wants to accomplish is entirely reasonable and potentially of interest to others (especially since these low-level iOS tasks can often be used on OS X as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer,

I had to modify SSZipArchive to insert a method that will extract a single file from the ZIP archive (Based on its name)

You could find [the modified version here](https://github.com/vexdev/ssziparchive), if someone finds this useful i might clean it up, add the delegate, the tests and propose for pull in SSZipArchive.

Usage is straightforward:

```
NSString *zipEntityToExtract = @"example.aac";
NSString *destinationFilePath = ...; //(Includes filename)
NSString *zipPath = ...;
[SSZipArchive unzipEntityName:zipEntityToExtract fromFilePath:zipPath toDestination:filePath];
//File is now in destinationFilePath
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, it's [encouraged that you accept it even if you're answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I will, it's just that i can't accept it before 2 days :)