# Access any file inside Zip File

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, zip

I am downloading folder `abc.zip` to my document directory from the server and I want to access `index.html` file without extracting that zip folder.

Is it possible to access the html file without extracting the zip file?

Comment: Yes it is possible to extract only one file from zip but the problem is how to do it in ios? I guess you need to search more on google regarding this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25016006/468724

Comment: Neither it is the solution nor it is the duplicate question. I did google but couldn't get the answer. as i said i want to access the html file without extracting zip file. above mentioned link is not the solution.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided in the above link? What issues are you getting from it?

Comment: SSZipArchive.unzipEntityName("index.html", fromFilePath: path, toDestination: unzipPath)

Comment: above is not working. I tried it. I mean at destination folder I cannot see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160194/discussion-between-iankit-and-inder-kumar-rathore).

Comment: I don't know why you're unable to use the above code, but I ran downloaded his repo:https://github.com/vexdev/ssziparchive and made few changes so that I can run it. In `SSZipArchiveTests` class there is a test method `testSingleElementUnzipping`, which is running successfully and is  able to extract one file from the archive. Just go through his code and make it workable for you.

Comment: The code works successfully for me but that files doesn't seem to me as I'm trying to see in iExplorer.